# Old movie (50 years +) where older couple get a machine that allows them to live through other people

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am looking for a movie I vaguely remember. I believe it's a British movie and I would guess from the late 60s/early 70s based on what I remember.

The plot is essentially that an elderly couple acquire some sort of item (a machine I believe) which allow them to live through other people. They enjoy the mobility of youth and the process of taking risks whilst in control of other peoples bodies. I am very vague on the details but I seem to remember it ends with a car crash whilst the old man is controlling someone.

Dos anybody know what I'm talking about?... I feel like I would know it if I saw it.

Comment: Do you recall if the movie was black & white or in colour? Also, in roughly which year (or range of years) did you actually see it?

Comment: It was a colour movie, I think I saw it around 15-20 years ago, found it on late night tv and got caught up in it. I would guess late 60s or early 70s for the era it was actually made.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is ***[The Sorcerers](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0062292/?ref_=tt_urv)*** (1967).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sorcerers):

> *The Sorcerers* is a 1967 British science fiction/horror film directed by Michael Reeves, starring Boris Karloff, Catherine Lacey, Ian Ogilvy, and Susan George. The original story and screenplay was conceived and written by John Burke. Reeves and his childhood friend Tom Baker re-wrote sections of the screenplay, including the ending at Karloff's insistence, wanting his character to appear more sympathetic. Burke was removed from the main screenwriting credit and was relegated to an 'idea by'.

From IMDB:

> An aging hypnotist creates a device that allows the user to control the mind of another person, but his wife abuses its power by manipulating a younger man to commit evil acts.

Near the end of the film -- at around the [1:23:33](https://youtu.be/WoPmKH_jL7U?t=5013) mark -- there's a scene where a young man crashes a car. It appears that the hypnotist and his wife were fighting for control over the young man at the time.

Comment: That's the one - damn that was quick - Ive been searching for hours... thank you

Comment: One of, but not the last Boris Karloff films. Susan George, 63 years younger, I think still working was in it. Always interesting how far back in time the "Six Degrees" of separation take you -- I believe there are living actors who were in the same film with people born in the 1860s or even 1850s--  that is about 170 years ago. Karloff would be 135 himself but was in silly teen flicks in the 1960s.